# How do I burn ubuntu to a cd so I can run it from the disc instead of having it saved to my harddrive?

Tags: downloads, iso, cd

I need to use ubuntu for a class project but don't want to have it installed on my computer.  I was told I could burn it to a disc and run it from there.  How do I do that?

I put the windows installer on the disc already but when I go to download ubuntu from that program, it asks me to make a password and user name and the only option it gives for location is my `C:\` drive. (i'm using windows7) and my disc drive is `D:\`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called **Ubuntu Live CD**, you can see a description on the [official ubuntu site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD#How-To_LiveCD_Ubuntu). Just follow that guide and you're all set.

---

### To create a LiveCd

[Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) Ubuntu. For a live CD, avoid the "alternate CD" & the Server Edition because it has no desktop. For installing, using the alternate CD is a good idea, if installing using the standard CD does not work.

[Make your own CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto). Cheap "write once" CDs in packs of 10 or more are usually best. You could burn a new CD once every 6 months to get the latest version but all version are supported for 18 months and long time support releases for 3 years. You could also use the remaining CDs for trying out other [distros](http://distrowatch.com/) Having a quick demo of other distros can help you understand Linux in general a LOT better a LOT faster, which helps you understand Ubuntu better.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu can no longer be put on CD, but **must** be burnt to a DVD. You can download the Ubuntu Image from http://www.ubuntu.com/download

Once downloaded, follow [these instructions from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Burn-a-CD-or-DVD-from-an-ISO-file) on how to burn the image to DVD.

Excerpt:

> 1. Insert a recordable CD, DVD, or Blu‑ray Disc into your disc burner.
> 2. Open Computer by clicking the Start button , and then clicking
>      Computer.
> 3. In Windows Explorer, find the disc image file, and then double-click
>      it.
> 4. If you have more than one disc burner, from the Disc burner list in
>      Windows Disc Image Burner, click the burner that you want to use.
> 5. (Optional) If you want to verify that the disc image was burned
>      correctly to the disc, select the Verify disc after burning check box.
> 6. If the integrity of disc image file is critical (for example, the disc
>      image file contains a firmware update), you should select this check
>      box.
> 7. Click Burn to burn the disc.

Once you've made the disc, put it in your DVD drive and restart your computer. If a startup menu comes up, select "Try Ubuntu Without Installing on Your Computer" to run as a Live Disc.

**Note** older Ubuntu versions (before 12.10) may be burnt to a CD